# Webpack for Storybook: Module not found for ts files with .web, .ios or .android extenstions

Tags: typescript, webpack, expo, storybook, react-native-web

I am trying to use Storybook, with expo and react-native-web.  Whenever I try to use an expo module I am getting the following error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/build/LinearGradient.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './NativeLinearGradient' in '/Fleyver/front/node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/build'
 @ ./node_modules/expo-linear-gradient/build/LinearGradient.js 1:1373-1406
```

The file that it cannot resolve has multiple extensions for .web.ts, .ios.ts and .android.ts, but there is no straight .ts extenstion

Being a beginner I am struggling with where to begin to fix this problem.  I am using this boilerplate to get started and everything works up until the expo modules

https://github.com/Naturalclar/expo-typescript-starter

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const threadLoader = require('thread-loader');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

const jsWorkerCommonOptions = {
  workers: 2,
  workerParallelJobs: 50,
  poolParallelJobs: 50
};

const babelWorkerOptions = {
  ...jsWorkerCommonOptions,
  name: 'babel-pool'
};

const tsWorkerOptions = {
  ...jsWorkerCommonOptions,
  name: 'ts-pool'
};

module.exports = ({ config, mode }) => {
  if (mode !== 'PRODUCTION') {
    threadLoader.warmup(babelWorkerOptions, ['babel-loader']);
    threadLoader.warmup(tsWorkerOptions, ['ts-loader']);
  }
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      { loader: 'cache-loader' },
      { loader: 'thread-loader', options: tsWorkerOptions },
      {
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          experimentalWatchApi: true,
          transpileOnly: true,
          happyPackMode: true
        }
      },
      { loader: 'react-docgen-typescript-loader' }
    ]
  });

  // type-checking
  config.plugins.push(
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({ checkSyntacticErrors: true })
  );

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/react-native-paper'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/react-native-elements'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/@expo/vector-icons'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/expo-linear-gradient'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/react-native-ratings'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/react-native-status-bar-height')
    ],
    use: [
      { loader: 'cache-loader' },
      { loader: 'thread-loader', options: babelWorkerOptions },
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory?true',
        options: {
          presets: [
            'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
            '@babel/preset-flow'
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  // react-native を import している箇所を react-native-web に変換
  config.resolve.alias['react-native$'] = require.resolve('react-native-web');

  config.resolve.alias['@expo/vector-icons'] = path.resolve(
    __dirname,
    '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  );

  // .ts, .tsx を含めるように追加
  config.resolve.extensions.push(
    '.ts',
    '.tsx'
  );
  return config;
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext '.ts, .tsx'",
    "type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
    "new": "scaffdog generate",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -h 192.168.1.64 -p 9001 -c .storybook -s .storybook/assets",
    "storybook:build": "build-storybook -c .storybook -s .storybook/assets",
    "klank": "klank storybook-static/index.html"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^3.0.3",
    "@expo/samples": "3.0.3",
    "expo": "^34.0.4",
    "expo-asset": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-camera": "~6.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~6.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~6.0.0",
    "klank": "^0.0.5",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.15",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "^5.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-options": "^5.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^5.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.1.10",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.1.10",
    "@storybook/theming": "^5.1.10",
    "@types/expo": "^32.0.13",
    "@types/expo__vector-icons": "^9.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.17",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.25",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.3",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.0.8",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.8.3",
    "@types/storybook__addon-actions": "^3.4.3",
    "@types/storybook__addon-knobs": "^5.0.3",
    "@types/storybook__react": "^4.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.13.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.2.0",
    "cache-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.3",
    "eslint-plugin-typescript": "^0.14.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^1.5.0",
    "jest-expo": "^34.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "react-art": "16.8.6",
    "react-docgen-typescript-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "scaffdog": "^0.1.2",
    "thread-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
    "tslint": "^5.18.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

When I run the various components in the app using any of the expo start methods, including `expo start --web`   I can see the components, however Storybook fails to load.  I am expecting to see the components load in a story for Storybook

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you need to push `.web.ts`, `.android.ts`, `.ios.ts` into `config.resolve.extensions`